# How to load binary values into registers?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

If I wanted to load a register with an immediate hex value, I'd do it like so:

```
MOV R2,#0xBEEF
```

but what if I want to load a register with a value that is only available to me in binary? For example, if I wanted to load the binary value 0010 0000 0000 1100 which is 200C in hex. Is there some special syntax like `#0b0010000000001100`? Or would I have to write a macro that could convert hex to binary?

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the software tool you are using.  So syntax questions are specific to a tool.  What tool are you using, and what did the documentation say?  I wouldnt expect the tools to have a binary format, but you might get luck.  binary to hex is pretty easy to convert just by looking, but if you have a lot of data, then sure you should write a script or program.

Comment: so, if you already know the value is 200C in hexa, why not `MOV R2,#0x200C`? Sounds a bit like "problem XY" to me, what exactly is forcing you to use binary form of the immediate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU assembler for ARM (AArch32) does accept base-2 constants in `0b0101` format anywhere a `0x` or other numeric literal is accepted.  Surprised you didn't just try it, since you already guessed right.

For example, `MOV R2, #0b0010000000001100`  assembles into

```
e302200c        movw    r2, #8204       ; 0x200c
```

with `gcc -c -marm arm-binary.s`.

You'd want to use `ldr r2, =0b010101` if it's not encodeable with a single `mov` instruction, like with `-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb`

```
mov r2, #0b111000
ldr r2, =0b010101
ldr R2, =0b0010000000001100
```

assembles with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb arm-binary.s` into this machine code:

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   2238            movs    r2, #56 ; 0x38
   2:   f04f 0215       mov.w   r2, #21
   6:   f242 020c       movw    r2, #8204       ; 0x200c
```

Comment: great, thanks. Should have listened to my gut, I guess. I don't think I'm using those flags with my `arm-none-eabi-gcc` command though so I'll have to try it with them later. also good to know that the `ldr reg, =label` pseudo-instruction is an approved alternative to a `mov` for immediate values out of range

Comment: The equivalent for the ARM armasm assembler is `MOV R2, #2_0010000000001100`, or `LDR R2, =2_0010000000001100`.